# Is the actor-model (akka) the right fit for my application?

Tags: akka, scalability, actor, akka-stream, akka-cluster

I've been reading blogs, listening to podcasts and reading the Akka documentation for a while now, but I can still not say I really understand if the actor-model is right for what I'm trying to solve.

Let's take the example of building an application that tells you what dog would best fit a person (not really what I'm making, but good for describing what I want to make).
I get **A LOT** of messages every second with people wanting to know what dog to buy and the system is supposed to decide what dog they should get based on information I have about the person.

1. **Event:**
   Person A wants a dog
2. **My subscriber:**
   Ok, person A wants a dog, lets check what dog to get them -> asks my application to figure this out
3. **Application:**

- Gets the request
- Collects more data about this person from other systems (where do they live, space they have, time, how sporty are they, etc etc)
- Asks threads/actors/whatnot to use a set of rules to check what kind of dog they should get

### Examples:

- Does the person live in any of these areas (checks a cache with areas which are good for big dogs) (most checks will be looking up things in lists)
- Does the person have a house bigger or smaller than x
- Does the person work long hours
- etc

All of these checks return a result to the application and the application collects all the answers until everything is done and will then decide on a result based on this.

Now bear in mind that there will be a lot of messages all the time and I want to run these checks concurrently to be able to answer as quickly as possible. The application will be running in a container in a Kubernetes cluster and I want to be able to scale the application when there is peak load or if the volume of messages increases in the future.

### My take so far

The actor-model seems right for the first part of my application (getting a request to find the right dog for a person) as it has its own state that it manages based on replies it gets from its child-actors/threads/whatever.

*However:* the workers that actually do the checks don't need an internal state as they are just checking if some information about the person is in list XYZ or if the person's house is bigger than X. (So not a good use of actors)

Therefore: Is the actor-model overkill for my application? What should I use in stead? Just futures? If I do use the actor-model should i use Akka Clustering? Is Akka streams an alternative?

I'm so confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

akka actors are great for managing state in the app. In your use case, the state could be cached result from these asks:

> ... data about this person from other systems (where do they live, space they have, time, how sporty are they, etc etc)

Caching these data in app memory and use actors for these in-memory data sounds a good use if you want to perform these asks as quickly as possible.

To perform the check, akka streams and graph DSL are your good choice.

```scala
val ask1 = Flow[Req].mapAsync(1) { req =>
  someActorRef ? req
}
val ask2 = ...

val bcast = b.add(Broadcast[Req](N))
val zip = b.add(Zip(...))
bcast.out(0) ~> ask1 ~> zip.in0
bcast.out(1) ~> ask2 ~> zip.in1
...
```

Feel free to read https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html to know more about akka streams. It can be easily integrated with akka actors and akka http.

Akka cluster or not is another question, definitely needs more info to make the decision, such as how large the user base is.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will look into akka streams and graph DSL.
My impression on akka cluster is that it's a good idea to use when you will have several nodes so that akka cluster can manage these for you, instead of having to manage them yourself.
Say I'd like to run 3 replicas of my application and I want them to pull work based on their capacity. Let's say I will have around 20 requests a second, each resulting in 100 checks. Also: after the dog has been decided the state about the person can be discarded by all actors.

Comment: Yah Akka cluster serves certain use cases well (for example, to keep data in sync between nodes) but it definitely introduces complexity and learning curve. Enjoy the adventure!

Comment: By the way, do you mind accepting the answer? Thanks